# Meteor Stripe Elements not rendering

Tags: meteor, stripe-payments, meteor-blaze, stripe.js

Am attempting to use Stripe elements form (v3) with a meteor form. All code runs without blowing up but nothing is rendered after `mount()` is called. Any ideas?

js:

```
Template.billing.onRendered(function(){
  let elements = stripe.elements();
  let style = {
    base: {
      // Add your base input styles here. For example:
      fontSize: '16px',
      color: "#32325d",
    }
  };
  let card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
  card.mount('#card-element');
  console.log("done");
})
```

html:

```
<template name="billing">
   <form id="payment-form">
    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element">
      </div>
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit Payment">
  </form>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, it was actually rendering but the width was 0 for some reason, so messing around with the css works.

Comment: Man thanks a lot, I got the same problem, it was driving me nuts !